# Doubt in Paper on Algebraic topology and Concurrency

Tags: algebraic-topology, computer-science, computational-geometry

I am trying to read a paper on Algebraic Topology and Concurrency (doi: 10.1016/j.tcs.2006.03.022), which claims to make use of Dijkstra's notation in talking about concurrency. Specifically, I am trying to understand the following lines, where $a,b,c$ are sephamores, and P and V are the locking and unlocking operations, respectively.

A=Pa.(Pb.Vb.Pc.Vc)*.Va

B=Pc.Pb.Vc.Pa.Va.Vb

PROG=A|B

What do the above lines mean? Specifically, what does the * mean in line 1, and line 3 in its entirety?

Comment: It seems that `*` means "repeated any number of times" and `|` means "in parallel".

Comment: This does not seem to have anything to do with algebraic topology and computational geometry.

Comment: @MoisheKohan maybe check out the paper then.

Comment: @AryanDugar: I am talking about your question, not the paper.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan, the question pertains to the paper, which pertains to the respective topics.